# What's the fastest way to iterate over a CvMat in Python using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm using OpenCV with Python to process a video stream. I'd like to implement my own algorithm, so I need to iterate over each frame.

What I have so far works, but way too slow to be real-time. I know that Python isn't the most efficient programming language, but I believe it can do much better than this, considering, that the built in image transformation functions are very fast. Numpy may be the way to go, but I'm not yet familiar with it.

```
import cv, numpy
vidFile = cv.CaptureFromFile( 'sample.avi' )
nFrames = int(  cv.GetCaptureProperty( vidFile, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT ) )
for f in xrange( nFrames ):
  frameImg = cv.QueryFrame( vidFile )
  frameMat=cv.GetMat(frameImg)
  print "mat ", mat[3,1]
  for x in xrange(frameMat.cols):
    for y in xrange(frameMat.rows):
        # just an example, multiply all 3 components by 0.5
        frameMat[y, x] = tuple(c*0.5 for c in frameMat[y, x])
  cv.ShowImage( "My Video Window",  frameMat )
  if cv.WaitKey( waitPerFrameInMillisec  ) == 27:
    break
```

How can I speed up the process?
Thanks, b_m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV has pretty good python documentation [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html). Basically you should always try to do operations on video frames using these builtin opencv functions, or numpy. For frame  processing take a look at [operations on arrays](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/core_operations_on_arrays.html), using this you can replace your entire pixel by pixel processing loop, which is absurdly slow:

```
frameMat=cv.GetMat(frameImg)
print "mat ", mat[3,1]
for x in xrange(frameMat.cols):
    for y in xrange(frameMat.rows):
        # just an example, multiply all 3 components by 0.5
        frameMat[y, x] = tuple(c*0.5 for c in frameMat[y, x])
cv.ShowImage( "My Video Window",  frameMat )
```

with:

```
cv.ConvertScale(frameImg, frameImg, scale=0.5)
cv.ShowImage( "My Video Window",  frameImg )
```

and easily play it in real time, there are loads of cool functions allowing you to merge videos etc.

Comment: I know that this is the right way, I've done that, but now I need to do some operations that I cannot execute without looping through the array. Well, it may be possible, but I can't figure it out how to. For example, how would you find the first (top-left) red pixel of the image? These things would be a piece of cake with loops.

Comment: @b_m - `frameImg[0,0]` will give you the RGB values for the top left pixel. Can you explain what you actually want to do? Then might be able to help more ;)

Comment: I mean the first pixel that is red.I don't even know what I wanna do in the long run, I just see, that it is inevitable to use loops at some point.

Comment: oh, I see, well you probably want to use the `feature detection` functions to find specific things. If you don't 'need' this right now I wouldn't worry about it until you do (if you're lucky you never will..). I sometimes split a frame into subrectangles and process these individually. Having to do actual pixelwise operations I find quite rare...and can be done before the video is played, so if it doesnt have to be in real time it doesnt matter.

Comment: @b_m - if these answers were useful to you please consider upvoting and or accepting them.. cheers.

Comment: It was useful, however I'm still looking for an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Python for loops are just too slow. If you can express your algorithm using the built-in functions (or numpy or another extension module), do that. For example, your multiply-by-constant example is easy to implement with ConvertScale. If the algorithm is more complicated, you'll have to implement it at C level. [Cython](http://cython.org/) is one popular way to make that easier.

Comment: This might be a good idea, I'll look into it. There's a project called opencv-cython, but it uses the opencv2.0.